# How to execute a custom sql query in apache spark against Big Query

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have a scenario where I need to execute custom query. The sql query basically deletes the table and creates the same table and insert some data.

sql is something like this

```
DROP TABLE DEMO.CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE DEMO.CUSTOMER AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    CUSTOMERID,
    CUSTOMERNAME
    FROM DEMO.COMPANY);
INSERT INTO DEMO.CUSTOMER(SELECT CUSTOMERID,CUSTOMERNAME FROM DEMO.COMPANY WHERE AV = 1;
```

How do I pass the above query in the below code?

```
        HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("credentials", serviceAccountKey);
        options.put("project", "customerProject");
        options.put("parentProject", "customerProject");
        options.put("table", sql);

        spark.read().format("bigquery").options(options).load();
```

In traditional jdbc the sql can be passed along with table parameter. But how do I do that with BQ?

Comment: Could you provide more details/scenario? Please provide details about your environment. How you want to do it? Usint API? Are you looking for something like solution described in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#java)?

Comment: @PjoterS Well, there is a way I can use api libraries to execute sql, but I want is to use sparkbigquery connector and execute the sql. I do not see why we need to use api client separately to execute a query.

For example if you are working with jdbc database instead of bigquery, spark has the feature where you can just pass the sql in the `dbtable` param and it executes the sql.

Comment: Did you try to put this this query into a variable and run it? like `querySql = "<yourQuery>"` and then run `result = spark.sql(querySql)`?